# Is there any JS library where I can adjust the column widths in a table like excel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-2

I need to be able to drag a "slider" to change the size of the columns like you can re-size columns in Excel. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one
http://dobtco.github.io/jquery-resizable-columns/

It also allows to save the position of columns in the local storage.